# Why aren't runAs=Server controls on this page accessible from VB?

Tags: vb.net

Okay, this one is just perplexing and annoying …. I’m hoping someone out there can help.

I have several aspx pages with server-side controls manipulated in the Visual Basic backing code; the vast majority work as advertised without any problems at all.   Then there's this guy:

In the aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="COVID-19 Staff Information" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="COVID-19.aspx.vb" Inherits="COVID_19_COVID_19" %>
…
<asp:Content ID="COVID_Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <div id="updateMeFromVB" runat="server"></div>
…
```

In the Visual Basic:

```
Partial Class COVID_19_COVID_19
…

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
…
        updateMeFromVB.InnerHtml = html
    End Sub
```

On compilation, I get:
*… COVID-19.aspx.vb(28,0): error BC30451: 'updateMeFromVB' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.*

HOWEVER, if I comment out that one line from Page_Load, it compiles great, put a breakpoint in the Page_Load subroutine, and when the breakpoint is hit do a “Quick Watch” on “updateMeFromVB” and there it is, all instantiated and happy.
[image: Quick Watch sees the variable]

I’ve been round and round this mulberry bush.   If I uncomment the updateMeFromVB.InnerHtml = html line, I get a compilation error – comment it out, and I can see the variable in the debugger.
Any clues?????

I’ve got other pages in the same solution where this is working just fine … over on one of those:

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CareLinkIndex.aspx.vb" Inherits="CareLink_Index" %>

…
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <!--#include file="GeneratedLinkList.htmlTxt" -->

    <div id="AdminOnlyDiv" runat="server" style="text-align: left">
…
```

VB:

```
Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    AdminOnlyDiv.Visible = IsMaintainer()
End Sub
```

Works great.

Comment: Extra oddity ... if I say "Yes" to the "There were build errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?" dialog.   Everything works properly.

The uncommented line sets the inner HTML of the control as it is supposed to -- it is apparently a Visual Studio build error ONLY.  If I ignore it, the code works just fine.

<sigh>

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the answer makes less sense than the question.  But I found a similar issue (#6217414) and the answer there was to rename the page.

Can't hurt, right?

So COVID-19.aspx is now CovidEmpPage.aspx ... and everything works like it should.

That absolutely should not have worked, and is definitely indicative of a bug in Visual Studio.